# iPhone:UI blocked when downloading data using NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using the `NSURLConnection` to download a video file from the server, at the same time playing the video by passing different url link to the movieplayer.
The problem is some blocking of the UI. During downloading we are unable to interact with the UI, like player zoom, pause button are blocked.
Code is like this for connection:_

```
connection1=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]] delegate:self];
```

in same mithod we are calling the

```
[playerInstance Play]
```

Please can you explain me where the problem is.

Comment: I think you do it in synchronous way. you should perform this operation in asynchronous method.

Comment: @Playcool is right. It seems you're using synchronous download. Can you post more code? It's not enough ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your problem exactly. But I think you doing the two works (downloadig, playing file) on a same thread, probably main thread. So this may happen. So try to run the two processes in a separate threads.

```
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(playfile:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadfile:) withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

You should make function for NSUrl operation and if it is already made call this function in following way for asynchronous communication.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(method) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

Comment: thanks, but as per my knowledge connection is Asynchronous here.

Comment: still UI block even we call downlaoding using performselector.We actuaaly using live streaming prtocol to play the video from server in MoviePlayer.When playing without downloading its playing perfectly